# Mail backing up to AOL.com

Tags: email, exchange

Having some trouble sending mail to AOL.com. Currently the queue is just sitting there in a retry state. I can't telnet to the MX records for AOL either. Reverse DNS looks fine as well. I'm getting these errors when using the connection tester.

```
Respond = 554 mtain-me01.r1000.mx.aol.com ESMTP not accepting connections,421 4.7.0 mtain-me01.r1000.mx.aol.com Error: too many errors
```

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're [not alone in this](http://www.rollernet.us/wordpress/2012/10/aol-delivery-trouble/).  It seems similar to this post about it on the [AOL PostMaster blog](http://postmaster-blog.aol.com/2010/11/10/internet-inbound-mail-delays/) from 2010.  There's nothing new on the AOL PostMaster blog so it's probably just a matter of waiting until they fix the problem.

Normal AOL errors have a link to a webpage or a code (554 RLY:B1) that explains what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something to confirm I wasn't alone in this.